# Confused about packages libc6-amd64 and libc6:amd64

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

While debugging (on a 64-bit system), `gdb` told me:

```
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.19.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).
```

Trying to track down (and resolve) this message led me to:

```
$ ls -l /lib64/ld-2.19.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 140928 Feb 25 12:00 /lib64/ld-2.19.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32 Feb 25 11:56 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
$ ls -l -L /lib64/ld-2.19.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 140928 Feb 25 12:00 /lib64/ld-2.19.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 149120 Feb 25 11:56 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$ for i in /lib64/ld-2.19.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so ; do dpkg -S $i; done
libc6-amd64: /lib64/ld-2.19.so
libc6:amd64: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
$ for i in libc6-amd64 libc6:amd64 ; do
> apt-cache policy $i
> apt-cache search $i
> done
libc6-amd64:i386:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 0
    500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.19-0ubuntu6 0
    500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
libc6-amd64 - Embedded GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libraries for AMD64
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 0
    500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.19-0ubuntu6 0
    500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

So `libc6-amd64` is `libc6-amd64:i386` and describes itself as "Embedded GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libraries for AMD64", while `libc6:amd64` is `libc6` and describes itself as "Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries" (via `dpkg -L`).

Can anyone explain the difference between these two packages? I am hesitant to remove anything whose name starts with `libc`, as I know of many paths to doorstop mode that begin with similar "simple" steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `libc6:amd64` is your native package never touch that, to see why try this `apt-cache rdepends libc6:amd64` to see all packages which need it.
- This `libc6-amd64:i386` is weird! AFAIK 32bit system can't run 64bit programs. It is ok to see `libc6-i386:amd64`,  but `libc6-amd64:i386`.

  Checking the packages that relay on it `apt-cache rdepends libc6-amd64:i386`. Only some packages which are basically: compiler, debugger, c libraries. Then it is just a 64bit cross-compile tool-chain prepared for Ubuntu 32bit.

  So it is useless in your case as you already have an 64bit system. You can remove it but check well the removal list before accept with yes.(you should see almost are `:i386` packages)

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove libc6-amd64:i386
  ```